# How does Google Desktop Search manage to stay light and fast?

Tags: performance, algorithm, google-desktop-search

I always wondered what different methods Google Desktop Search is using so that it uses least CPU and memory while indexing a computer containing more 100,000 files on an average.

In just few hours it has indexed the whole system and I did not see it eating up my CPU, memory etc.

If any of you have done some research, please do share.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is simple: It starts to work then very soon stops and just sits there in in memory, doing nothing. Of course it's then totally useless but at least, it keeps light and fast. Sorry, couldn't resist :-) I Switched to Windows Search 4.0 and I'm much happier about it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't...

I installed it on one computer, and quickly removed it because it was intrusive (although this can be probably configured) and hungry (particularly on a low end PC).

It is installed on a laptop near me right now, and if I compare it to a couple of small utilities I run permanently (SlickRun, CLCL, my AutoHotkey script...) it uses more than 10 times their CPU and 5 to 20 times their memory. Times two, since, for some reason, I have one instance running another, plus the ToolbarNotifier (less hungry).
Even Trend Micro anti-virus uses less memory and CPU.

Perhaps I will try it again when I will get a more modern PC with lot of memory, but right now I am happy enough with some grep utilities, even if they are slower.

Comment: Did you allow it to complete it's initial index? It cannot magically know about every file on your computer, it has to index them first.. After that is done, the resource-usage will be *far* smaller

Comment: I didn't installed it on the mentioned laptop, but it seems to have finished its indexing tasks (57,834 files indexed, index of 390MB for ~30GB of files).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at disk usage.  If you build many keys/indexes you will use lots of disk space and the searches will be fast.

For example;
30 gig drive 75% used. 3.6 gig used for 2 instances of Google Desktop.  (roaming profiles suck)

Answer (score 0):

Once it has done the initial index, and written it to disc, it doesn't need to anything.

Searching using the index will require very little resources, the only thing that will is indexing new or modified files..